# 18.04 Server Systemd DHCP hangs on DISCOVER, dhclient works

Tags: networking, server, systemd, dhcp, dhcpd

Just installed ubuntu server 18.04. I am unable to get a dhcp lease using systemd-networkd, but using dhclient works fine.

With SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug I get:

```
$ journalctl
...
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: enp3s0: Link state is up-to-date
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: enp3s0: found matching network '/etc/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp3s0.network'
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: wlp2s0: Link is not managed by us
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: LLDP: Started LLDP client
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: enp3s0: Started LLDP.
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: enp3s0: Acquiring DHCPv4 lease
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: DHCP CLIENT (0xb7fc15eb): STARTED on ifindex 2
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: enp3s0: Discovering IPv6 routers
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: NDISC: Started IPv6 Router Solicitation client
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=9 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 4s
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: DHCP CLIENT (0xb7fc15eb): DISCOVER
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: lo: Link state is up-to-date
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: lo: Unmanaged
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_31 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=10 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer systemd-timesyncd[581]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Apr 29 10:14:09 computer sudo[2164]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 29 10:14:11 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: DHCP CLIENT (0xb7fc15eb): DISCOVER
Apr 29 10:14:12 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: DHCP CLIENT (0xb7fc15eb): DISCOVER
Apr 29 10:14:14 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 8s
Apr 29 10:14:16 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: DHCP CLIENT (0xb7fc15eb): DISCOVER
Apr 29 10:14:21 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: NDISC: No RA received before link confirmation timeout
Apr 29 10:14:21 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: NDISC: Invoking callback for 't'.
Apr 29 10:14:22 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 17s
Apr 29 10:14:25 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: DHCP CLIENT (0xb7fc15eb): DISCOVER
Apr 29 10:14:39 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 34s
Apr 29 10:14:41 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: DHCP CLIENT (0xb7fc15eb): DISCOVER
Apr 29 10:15:14 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation, next solicitation in 1min 10s
Apr 29 10:15:14 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: DHCP CLIENT (0xb7fc15eb): DISCOVER
Apr 29 10:16:18 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: DHCP CLIENT (0xb7fc15eb): DISCOVER
```

When I use dhcpd things work just fine:

```
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer sudo[2213]:    user : TTY=tty1 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/dhclient -v enp3s0
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer sudo[2213]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by user(uid=0)
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer dhclient[2214]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer dhclient[2214]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer dhclient[2214]: All rights reserved.
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer dhclient[2214]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer dhclient[2214]:
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer dhclient[2214]: Listening on LPF/enp3s0/c0:3f:d5:63:0a:30
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer dhclient[2214]: Sending on   LPF/enp3s0/c0:3f:d5:63:0a:30
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer dhclient[2214]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Apr 29 10:33:00 computer dhclient[2214]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x536ea71d)
Apr 29 10:33:02 computer dhclient[2214]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.64.102 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1da76e53)
Apr 29 10:33:02 computer dhclient[2214]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.64.102 from 192.168.64.1
Apr 29 10:33:02 computer dhclient[2214]: DHCPACK of 192.168.64.102 from 192.168.64.1
Apr 29 10:33:02 computer systemd-networkd[2169]: enp3s0: Adding address: 192.168.64.102/24 (valid forever)
```

My questions are:

- Has anybody perhaps seen this and know what the cause could be?
- Is there any way to find out why it fails to talk with the dhcp server?
- Is there a safe way (robust to system updates) to make it use dhclient instead?

I have a limited time to get this working before I have to leave and I need to know that it will come back up online without local intervention in case of a reboot.

Edit: the requested information:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network  
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 73
       serial: ac:7b:a1:43:12:c8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-48-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:92 memory:d0700000-d0701fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0c
       serial: c0:3f:d5:63:0a:30
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.64.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0604000-d0604fff memory:d0600000-d0603fff
```

netplan:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5). 
network:   
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

Also:

```
$ cat /run/systemd/network/*
[Match]
Name=enp3s0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[DHCP]
UseMTU=true
RouteMetric=100
```

I've also tried without the [DHCP] stanza and without the LinkLocalAddressing line (shouldn't matter of course) to no avail.

Thanks.

Edit 2: For a later stage in the setup I need to set up a pppoe interface. I now realized that netplan and networkd doesn't support pppoe configuration, so I'm giving up on this and going back to NetworkManager.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Added the info.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It looks like you may have a cabling problem. Please describe your cabling from the computer all the way to the router/modem.

Comment: I doubt it's cabling. dhcpd would not be able to connect either in that case. It's a single ethernet cable from the machine to the wall socket (then onto the building wide provider).

To be clear, no other device here has had any trouble connecting with dhcp, including this one when using dhcpd. The only thing that fails is the networkd supplied dhcp client.

Comment: If you notice in your lshw command where it says `speed=100Mbit/s`, you should be getting `1Gbit/s` speed... 10 times faster. You either have a cabling problem, or some device that's not auto-negotiating properly... a switch/hub/router. That's why I asked you to describe your cabling. Have you tried a **different** cat 5E or cat 6 cable to the wall outlet? Have you tried connecting to a different wall plate? You may have to contact the building provider for help with a fix.

Comment: My remote is 100mbit/s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same problem. Although the question is 6 months old, I think it may help others so I posted my solution here.

I ran the tcpdump (`tcpdump -n ether host <mac> and port 67 and port 68 -vvv`) to inspect the differences in the DHCP Discover packet sent by networkd and dhclient, and found the Client ID set by networkd is a self-generated 18 bytes ID as Client ID, but dhclient is just the MAC address.

The DHCP server probably expects a MAC on Client ID.

Thus the problem can be solved by adding `dhcp-identifier: mac` in netplan config, e.g:

```
network:   
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
```

Comment: Thank you - that looks like the issue. I don't want to change my config (ended up using network manager) so I can't test it on the same system, but this is excellent information for the future.